# Для чего в HTML5 используется элемент <base>?

Tags: html5

При изучении HTML наткнулся на элемент `<base>`, но в интернете не нашел нормального простого объяснения. Подскажите простым языком что это за элемент

Comment: что конкретно непонятно [из объяснения в интеренете](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)?

Comment: Для чего именно он используется

Comment: И желательно с примерам объяснить

Comment: Там по ссылке и определение и использование есть с примерами. Если вам что то не ясно оттуда, будьте конкретны в вопросе, что именно не ясно?

Answer (score 1):

Элемент base определен внутри контейнера head и инструктирует браузер относительно полного базового адреса текущего документа. Тег base предназначен для документов, в которых используется относительный адрес и эти документы могут переноситься в другую папку или даже на другой компьютер без потери связи. Браузер ищет тег base, определяет полный адрес документа и корректно загружает его.

Comment: Не знаю,можно ли найти объяснение проще,думаю вам это объяснение поможет!